# Asp.net core Multiple query on a table in a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I am working on a Asp.net Core 2 project. There are multi part in my `index.cshtml` . Please see the picture below.

[image]

Also i have a table named `News_Tbl` that all news insert in this table (`News_Tbl` contains `NewsId`,`NewsTitle`,`NewsContent`,`NewsType`).

**NewsType Value :**

1 = Sport News

2 = breaking News

3 = Economic News

4 = Health News

5 = Foreign news

Also, each section in `index.cshtml` view is a `PartialView`. As you can see I need several query on `News_Tbl` query.

**My query in `index` Action**

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        ViewBag.SportNews = _context.News_Tbl.Select(n => n.NewsType == 1).Take(18).ToList();
        ViewBag.BrekingNews = _context.News_Tbl.Select(n => n.NewsType == 2).Take(8).ToList();
        ViewBag.EconomicNews = _context.News_Tbl.Select(n => n.NewsType == 3).Take(15).ToList();
        ViewBag.HealthNews = _context.News_Tbl.Select(n => n.NewsType == 4).Take(15).ToList();
        ViewBag.ForeignNews = _context.News_Tbl.Select(n => n.NewsType == 5).Take(8).ToList();


        return View();
    }
```

As you can see, a query is written for each section and send by a `ViewBag` to `index.cshtml`. I want to know is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Manoz But each news entities wants a query. Is there a way optimize it?

Comment: Load on demand, initially load html, then using ajax calls get all the data asynchronously. it will make UI light wait.

Answer (score 1):

Use [view components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Create a new folder in your project called `ViewComponents`. Inside add a class like `NewsViewComponent`, with something like the following:

```
public class NewsViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly MyNewsService _service;

    public NewsViewComponent(MyNewsService service)
    {
        _service = service ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(service));
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(NewsType type)
    {
        // use `_service` to get news filtered by `type`
        return View(news);
    }
}
```

`MyNewsService` above is just a placeholder to show how to inject something into the view component to retrieve your news. Replace this with whatever you actually need to use, a context, some API service, etc.

Then, add the view, `Views\Shared\Components\News\Default.cshtml`, and inside add the HTML code necessary to render your list of news articles.

Finally, in your main view or layout - wherever you need to actually show the lists of news articles - render each area via:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("News", new { type = NewsType.SportsNews })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows -

Create a custom Model say `NewsModel` which accepts list that you pass via controller. I am assuming that `_context.News_Tbl` is `IQueryable` type. That you can change on the basis of your needs.

```
   public class NewsModel
   {
        public List<News_Tbl> SportsNews { get; set; }
        public List<News_Tbl> BrekingNews { get; set; }
        public List<News_Tbl> EconomicNews { get; set; }
        public List<News_Tbl> HealthNews { get; set; }
        public List<News_Tbl> ForeignNews { get; set; }

    public NewsModel(IQueryable<News_Tbl> list)
    {
        this.SportsNews = list.Where(n => n.NewsType == 1).Take(18).ToList();
        this.BrekingNews = list.Where(n => n.NewsType == 2).Take(8).ToList();
        this.EconomicNews = list.Where(n => n.NewsType == 3).Take(15).ToList();
        this.HealthNews = list.Where(n => n.NewsType == 4).Take(15).ToList();
        this.ForeignNews = list.Where(n => n.NewsType == 5).Take(8).ToList();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
      var model = new NewsModel(_context.News_Tbl);    
      return View(model);
    }
```

Now you can use this list in your view as we generally do with viewmodel.